# Как получить текущего пользователя в модели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть два объекта: `Пользователь` и `Продукт`. У пользователя есть скидка, у продукта есть цена и еще есть одна функция, которая считает цену со скидкой смотря на пользователя.

Не удается получить текущего пользователя...
Как сделать функцию `get_discount_price` в модели `Product`?

модели:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(default='', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(default='', null=True, blank=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
        ordering = ('-date_create',)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    file = ResizedImageField(size=[1000, 700], quality=100, verbose_name='Картинка', upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d/',
                             null=True, blank=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def get_discount_price(self):
        total = self.price - (int((self.price / 100)) * self.request.user.account.discount)
        return total

    def datepublished(self):
        return self.date_create.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(str(self.id) + self.title)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'
        ordering = ('-date_create',)
```

Comment: просто request.user.account.discount?

Comment: @Jack_oS нет, если взять в models.py request.user.account.discount, он не находит, я хочу в jinja написать так {{ product.get_discount_price }} и он считает сумму со скидкой который у пользователя